# How to make a chat client for the iPhone

Tags: c#, javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, I'm starting the development of a native iPhone app which will implement a chat interface. So far the implementation seems to be pretty complicated, I've read of Websockets, XMPP/Jabber and raw TCP/IP sockets, but have no idea which to use. The client will be programmed in Objective-C, and I would like to program the server in C# (and not have to pay $100/month for a hosting service).

What would you guys suggest?

Comment: What is it for, exactly? Chat clients exist; is this for a special in-house development or something? Generally server overhead is to be avoided at all costs…we might be able to give a better answer if we knew what it was for.

Comment: Well it's a very basic chat, just need to send and receive messages from a chat room (there will be several chat rooms you can join). There will also be other custom features in the app about how the chat rooms are created, and will have custom user profiles. I understand how to do all of that (databasing, etc.) except for how the actual messages should be sent and received from the chat room

Comment: Please let me know if I can clarify any more, it's really important that we start with the right technology. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like XMPP/Jabber as there are already a ton of libraries in existence for pretty much every language under the sun.  That would allow you to focus on the unique aspects of your app rather than having to worry about implementing a protocol. Check out [the XMPP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) website for a list of libraries for both clients and servers.

With regards to hosting, C# might be difficult to find free hosting simply because it requires a Windows installation which requires a non-free license.  You can find cheap Windows hosting through somebody like GoDaddy, but you won't be able to find free (at least I doubt it).

Comment: We already have hosting at godaddy and that would be fine, as long as we don't to pay for a dedicated server =). So how could I implement XMPP/Jabber on the server? Does it work through a web page or what? I find these new protocols baffling, what happened to the good old days where you just have to open a connection between client and server? lol

Comment: @Rob, basically, it's going to likely depend on the library.  You may actually be able to find a fully functional Jabber server that you don't need to modify in any way, you just configure it a bit and then let it run.

Comment: How would this server be set up though? I have no problem even coding my own protocols, but I'm very confused as to how to do all the server side stuff. Can I just host a C# program that gets TCP/IP connections, or should I do it through a web page? Like I have never done anything like this before and I don't have any idea where to even start.

Comment: If you get a lot of app installs, GoDaddy isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Rob, it depends on the protocol but likely you have a TCP socket on the server.  Clients connect to that socket and maintain the connection for the life of the session.  They pass data back and forth through that socket.  Using a web server probably wouldn't be a good idea because it would be more difficult to establish who is "online" and who is not.  However, if you don't need to have any notion of session then it would work just fine.  Ultimately, you need to read about the protocol specification to understand exactly how the sever behaves.  There are a number of ways to accomplish this.